# Distribute values in an array to three different arrays in a loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

Here's a beginner question.

I'm trying to distribute the following values into three different arrays.

```
var values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
```

The result of that would be: `[[1,4,7][2,5,8][3,6]]`
... So basically like distributing candy to three kids in a row till the candy runs out. I've looked around and people seem to ask about array blocks like [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8]], but this is kinda different.

These are my variables:

```
var values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var numberOfArrays = 3;
var parentArray = [];
```

I don't know how to start the looping. Do I loop through my **values** first?

```
for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    // Code here?
}
```

Please help. I don't know how to organize this logic :/

Comment: Well google sucks, or I suck at searching. This is what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: You result is wierd, if I distribute candies to kids by the order, it should be: `[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6]]`, right ? You're using the candy `5` twice.

Comment: Haha. That was a simple typo. Thanks

Comment: Tbh i didn't google it, i searched my browser history, i just remembered being on a similar topic recently. I don't know if it would be easy or hard to find on a search engine.

Comment: `var values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var numberOfArrays = 3;
var parentArray = [];
var arrayNumber = 0;
var index = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfArrays; i++) {
  parentArray[i] = [];
}

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  parentArray[i % numberOfArrays][index] = values[i];
  if (i % numberOfArrays === numberOfArrays - 1) {
    index++;
  }
}`

However, this gives [[1,4,8],[2,5,9],[3,6]] which is what I think your were actually trying to do

Comment: Much shorter and easier way to do this:

`for(var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
 index = (i % numberOfArrays);
 parentArray[index] = parentArray[index] || [];
 parentArray[index].push(values[i]);
}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [reminder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) for the right inner array and push the value to it.

```js
var values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    gap = 3,
    result = values.reduce((r, v, i) => {
        r[i % gap] = r[i % gap] || [];
        r[i % gap].push(v);
        return r;    
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```